# Flatten laravel nested relationship (parent to descendants)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a parent children relationship on my model. What I want is to flatten all those collection including all those descendants of parent.

```
[
   {
      'name': 'Parent',
      'another_array' => [

          {
             'name': 'Another Array Name'
          }
      ],
      'children': [
         {
             'name': 'First Child',
             'address': 'lorem ipsum',
             'contact_no': '92390',


             'another_array' => [

                 {
                    'name': 'Another Array Name'
                 }
             ],
             'children': [
                {
                    'name': 'First Descendant',
                    'address': 'lorem ipsum',
                    'contact_no': '92390',
                    'children': [
                        {
                            'name': 'Descendant Child',
                            'address': 'lorem ipsum',
                            'contact_no': '92390',
                            'children': [
                                {
                                   'name': 'Last Descendant',
                                   'address': '',
                                   'contact_no': '',
                                   'children': []
                                }
                            ]

                        }
                    ]
                }
             ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I tried the code below. However it only displays the second depth of children. It does not display the next children of the collection.

```
User.php
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{

    return $this->hasMany(User::class,'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function descendants()
{
    return $this->children()->with('descendants');
}

UsersController.php

public function index()
{
    $parent = User::find(1);

    $parent->with('descendants')->find($parent->id);

    $descendants = $this->traverseTree($parent->descendants);

    return response($descendants);
}

protected function traverseTree($subtree)
{
    $descendants = collect([]);

    foreach ($subtree->descendants as $descendant) {

       $descendants->push($descendant);

       if($descendant->descendants instanceof Collection) {

          foreach ($descendant->descendants as $node) {

             $this->traverseTree($node);

             $descendants->push($node);
          }
       }
   }

   return $descendants;
}
```

Desired Output

```
    [
        {
            'name': 'Parent',
            'address': 'lorem ipsum',
            'contact_no': '92390'
        },
        {
            'name': 'First Child',
            'address': 'lorem ipsum',
                 'contact_no': '92390'
        },
        {
            'name': 'First Descendant',
            'address': 'lorem ipsum',
                 'contact_no': '92390',
        },
        {
            'name': 'Descendant Child',
            'address': 'lorem ipsum',
                 'contact_no': '92390',
        },
        {
            'name': 'Last Descendant' ,
            'address': '',
                 'contact_no': '',
        }

    ]
```

I am looking forward for your help.

Answer (score 2):

from your collection response convert it to an array by chaining the `toArray()` method so you output becomes and a multi-dimensional array instead of nested objects as shown below...

```php
       $my_array = [
            'name' => 'Parent',
            'children' => [
                 'name' => 'First Child',
                 'address' => 'lorem ipsum',
                 'contact_no' => '234',
                 'children' => [
                    'name' => 'First Descendant',
                     'address' => 'lorem ipsum',
                     'contact_no' => '567',
                    'children' => [
                        'name' => 'Descendant Child',
                        'address' => 'lorem ipsum',
                        'contact_no' => '8890',
                        'children' => [
                            'name' => 'Last Descendant',
                            'address' => '',
                            'contact_no' => '',
                            'children' =>  []
                        ]
                    ]
                 ]
            ]
        ];
```

then you can use this helper function below:

```php
protected function _flattened($array)
    {
        $flatArray = [];

        if (!is_array($array)) {
            $array = (array)$array;
        }

        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                $flatArray = array_merge($flatArray, $this->_flattened($value));
            } else {
                $flatArray[0][$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $flatArray;
    }
```

when you dump the `$result = $this->_flattened($my_array);`, you will have output like...

```php
       [
            0 => [
                "name" => "Parent"
            ],
            1 => [
                "name" => "First Child",
                "address" => "lorem ipsum"
                "contact_no" => "234"
            ],
            2 => [
                "name" => "First Descendant"
                "address" => "lorem ipsum"
                "contact_no" => "567"
            ],
            3 => [
                "name" => "Descendant Child"
                "address" => "lorem ipsum"
                "contact_no" => "8890"
            ],
            4 => [
                "name" => "Last Descendant"
                "address" => ""
                "contact_no" => ""
            ],
        ];
```

Comment: Are you sure about the array_walk_recursive? Because the output is giving me wrong output.

Comment: @Jearson what's you output like? ensure it's multi-dimensional array

Comment: For the sake of demo purposes I did not included other attributes like address, contact_no and etc.. When I included that it will also be added to the array output.

Comment: @Jearson i have a solution for you now, i will update my previous answer posted

Comment: Your answer is working for one nested relation in this case for children. But if I eager load another relationship (e.g another_array), the output will append the another_array. I updated the data on the question. Let us say the array has another another_array..

Comment: the answer i provided was based on the sample data you gave initially, of course it won't work in all scenarios, because what you just updated is totally different from what was their initially. also as you sample input have changed, i expected the desired out format should change also

Comment: I am sorry for that. Also for not including other data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196478/discussion-between-kheengz-and-jearson).