# Laravel get all products from parent category and all it's sub-categories

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, nested

I'm trying to retrieve products from a category and all it's sub-categories.

Here's my `categories` table :

```
| id    | parent_id     | name          |
|----   |-----------    |-------------  |
| 1     | NULL          | Electronics   |
| 2     | 1             | Computers     |
| 3     | 2             | Accessories   |
| 4     | 3             | Keyboards     |
```

and here's my products table :

```
| id    | category_id   | name          |
|----   |-------------  |-----------    |
| 1     | 2             | Product 1     |
| 2     | 3             | Product 2     |
| 3     | 4             | Product 3     |
```

Let's say i'm in `Computers` category page, and i want to display products from this table and all it's childrens.

so it should get products first from `Computers` and `Accessories` and also `Keyboards`.

Here's my **Category** Model :

```
public function parent() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function childs() {
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function products() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, Category::class, 'parent_id', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

**Product** Model :

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
}
```

**Query** :

```
Category::with(['products', 'childs.products'])->where('id', $category->id)->get();
```

**Return** :

```
{
    "id":11,
    "parent_id":4,
    "name":"Computers",
    "products":[
        {
            "id":2,
            "category_id":12,
            "title":"Product 1",
            "laravel_through_key":11
        }
    ],
    "childs":[
        {
            "id":12,
            "parent_id":11,
            "name":"Accessories",
            "products":[
                {
                    "id":1,
                    "category_id":13,
                    "user_id":1,
                    "title":"Product 2",
                    "laravel_through_key":12
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Above, it's escaping the last child category `Keyboards`.

I have tried to use `hasManyThrough` relationship but i only got products from `Computers` and `Accessories` but didn't reach to `Keyboards`.

So if i'm on a category i want to get all products from this category tree. even if a sub-category has sub-categories.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks.

**Update** :

i applied the snippet in *Foued MOUSSI*'s answer :

```
public function childrenRecursive() {
    return $this->childs()->with('childrenRecursive');
}

$categoryIds = Category::with('childrenRecursive')->where('id', $category->id)->get();
```

**Return** :

```
[
    {
        "id":2,
        "parent_id":1,
        "name":"Computers",
        "children_recursive":[
            {
                "id":3,
                "parent_id":2,
                "name":"Accessories",
                "children_recursive":[
                    {
                        "id":4,
                        "parent_id":3,
                        "name":"Keyboards",
                        "children_recursive":[]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and i got the array of category and all it's sub-categories, but to get products from all these categories i need to extract the IDs from the the list with `childrenRecursive` to call something like :

```
Product::whereIn('category_id', $categoryIds)->get();
```

Any idea?

Comment: what is your current query now ?

Comment: What database and version are you using?

Comment: @Qonvex620 added it to the question.

Comment: @Rwd ```mysql``` with laravel version ```5.8```

Comment: Could you add a Json representation of the desired result ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI added the json output.

Comment: the main category "id":11 shouldn't be = '2' regarding  the where('id', 2) ??

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Ah, i just typed that id hardcoded for an example not in my real code. will edit this.

Comment: In the example you're not loading `Keyboards`, are you wanting the the query to get the just the direct children or all descendants of a category? Also, what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Rwd ```mysqld  Ver 10.3.16-MariaDB for Win64 on AMD64```

Comment: Did either answer help you solve your issue or are you still having problems?

Comment: at first i used @FouedMOUSSI example, and it reached what i need, but still don't know how to get array of ids from the recursive list, to be able to get products whereIn these ids. if you can help with that?

Comment: I'm on it
Let me try it first and i will go back to you

Comment: Sure, take your time!

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you could get the products in or under a certain category.

Answer (score 6):

You may fix it by :

make a recursive relation: (Please Refer to Alex Harris answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43989776/6514992))

```
// recursive, loads all descendants
// App\Category
public function childrenRecursive()
{
   return $this->childs()->with('childrenRecursive');
}

$data = Category::with(['products', 'childrenRecursive', 'childrenRecursive.products'])->where('id', 2)->get()->toArray();
```

**#Edit:** Extract list of products

Define [Flatten laravel recursive relationship collection (tree collections)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57040121/6514992) function inside your controller

```
public function flatten($array)
{
        $flatArray = [];

        if (!is_array($array)) {
            $array = (array)$array;
        }

        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value) || is_object($value)) {
                $flatArray = array_merge($flatArray, $this->flatten($value));
            } else {
                $flatArray[0][$key] = $value;
            }
        }

        return $flatArray;
}
```

Then in order to only have products item

```
$data = Category::with(['products', 'childrenRecursive', 'childrenRecursive.products'])->where('id', 2)->get()->toArray();

$flatten = $this->flatten($data);

foreach ($flatten as $key => $fl) {
    // eliminate categories from $flatten array
    if (!array_key_exists('category_id', $fl)) {
        unset($flatten[$key]);
    }
}

$product = array_values($flatten);
```

Comment: This will only get the first level of nesting.

Comment: The first code before adding the recursive returned the same results. but after you updated that, it worked and reached the last child. that's good, what if i need to get only the products then out of this long list?

Comment: You mean getting only top level category products ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI No i mean all products from the list containing products within the childs recursive.

Comment: In this case, i think you need to loop through each category / sub category then retrieve its list of products and store them in separate array.

Comment: i think you didn't get it, after applying your code snippet, it returned categories with it's products and childrens with products.

How can i fetch only products from this parent and childrens.

Comment: The easy way : extract the main category and its relevant sub categories IDS in an array, then simply call : Product::whereIn('category_id', IDS)->get();

Comment: That's a good one, can you please provide me with an example in your answer for how i can extract the Ids? sorry for taking much of your time.

Comment: Since we already get list of product in 1 query, i prefered working directly on list returned by $data = Category::with(['products', 'childrenRecursive', 'childrenRecursive.products'])->where('id', 2)->get()->toArray();

See updated answer

Comment: Your code also worked, i want to thank you for your help and sorry for taking much of your time.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: Sadly this is returning only first level of nesting for me

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to use something like [laravel-adjacency-list](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list). This would allow you to use [CTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) to recursively load the relationships.

Below are the steps to get you set up (at the time of writing)

1. Run `composer require staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list:"^1.0"`
2. Add the `HasRecursiveRelationships` trait to your `Category` model:

   ```
   use Staudenmeir\LaravelAdjacencyList\Eloquent\HasRecursiveRelationships;

   class Category extends Model
   {
       use HasRecursiveRelationships;

       ...
   }
   ```
3. Change your query to be:

   ```
   Category::with('descendants.products')->where('id', $id)->first(); //$id being the id of the parent category you want to get.
   ```

---

If you're wanting to just get the products that are in/under a category you could do something like:

```
Product::whereHas('category', function ($query) use ($category) {
    $query->whereIn('categories.id', $category->descendantsAndSelf()->select('id')->getQuery());
})->get();
```

For more information on how to use `laravel-adjacency-list` please refer to the [documentation](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list).

Comment: i've tried the last ```Product``` query, i got full list of products. what if i need to pass a specific category to get all products under this category and it's subs?

and also the ```whereHas('category...``` what is ```'category'```?

Comment: @AmrSubZero That's what the last query is doing. `$category` is the `Category` that you want to get the products for e.g. `$category = Category::findOrFail(3);`

Comment: i get ```Call to undefined method App\Product::category()``` that's why i'm asking.
and btw the first query is returning incorrect hierarchical order, it gets the last child category as separated not inside the tree.

Comment: @AmrSubZero Do you have a relationship for category set up in your `Product` model? If so, change the whereHas call to be `whereHas('name-of-relationship')`. If not add a `belongsTo` relationship called `category` to the `Product` model. As for the making the relationship into a tree, there doesn't (currently) appear to be a way to do this package as is. I would suggest opening an issue in the Github repo or looking at https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset.

Comment: It worked, got the products from all, Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: @AmrSubZero Glad I could help! If this has answered your question please may you marked it as accepted :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```php
$categories  = Category::whereParentId(null)->with('children.children.children')->get();
```

and in view your can display items with foreach loop

Comment: is there any way we can judge how many times we have to write children.children.children when hierarcy levels are not fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm using MySQL 5, I used this way to resolve this issue in my project if anyone is interested about it. It makes more sense for me.

If you're using MySQL 8, you can take this question as a reference to edit this code.
[How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)

```
public function scopeWhereCategoryId($query, $category_id){
    return $query->where(function($query) use ($category_id){
        $query->where('category_id', trim($category_id));
        $query->orWhereRaw("category_id in (
            select  id
            from    (select * from pm_categories
                    order by category_id, id) categories_sorted,
                    (select @pv := '" . trim($category_id) . "') initialisation
            where   find_in_set(category_id, @pv)
            and     length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', id))
        )");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use ORM Eloquent Relationship

```
public function categoriesProduct(ProductCategory $category)
{
     $categories = ProductCategory::where('parent_id', $category->id)
                                  ->orWhere('id', $category->id)
                                  ->latest()
                                  ->get();
     return view('categoryProduct', compact('categories', 'category'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the better way is article
[Eloquent: Recursive hasMany Relationship with Unlimited Subcategories](https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-recursive-hasmany-relationship-with-unlimited-subcategories/)

Just add products relationship to the Category Model

```
Class Category extends Model

public function categories()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
 }

 public function childrenCategory()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id')->with('categories');
 }

 public function products()
 {
     return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
 }
```

**Query:**

```
 $Categories = Category::whereNull('parent_id')
->with('childrenCategory','products')
->get();
```

**Returns:**

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "parent_id": null,
    "name": "Category 1",
    "description": "Category 1",
    "created_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
    "products": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category_id": 1,

        "name": "productNobis provident.",
        "description": "Ad quia ullam voluptatem modi ab dolorem non.",
        "qty": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z"
    },
    ],
    "children_categories": [
    
    ]
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "parent_id": null,
    "name": "Category 2",
    "description": "Laborum aut quibusdam earum commodi.",
    "created_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
    "products": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "category_id": 2,
        "name": "productVoluptas laborum adipisci.",
        "description": "Autem ut et voluptate ab sit voluptatem quia.",
        "qty": 1,
        "created_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z"
    },
    ],
    "children_categories": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "parent_id": 2,
        "name": "Category 4",
        "description": "Eos nemo libero non eius voluptates.",
        "created_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
        "products": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "category_id": 4,
            "name": "productSunt deleniti minus.",
            "description": "Vitae numquam autem consequuntur consequuntur.",
            "qty": 1,
            "created_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z"
        },
        ],
        "categories": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "parent_id": 4,
            "name": "Rerum qui earum.",
            "description": "Nihil ipsum officiis vitae et error accusamus ipsam.",
    
            "created_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
            "products": [
            {
                "id": 13,
                "category_id": 6,
        
                "name": "productConsequatur quisquam molestiae.",
                "description": "Autem sed mollitia eos eveniet iste ipsa aut aliquam.",
                "qty": 1,
                "created_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-12-10T11:43:48.000000Z"
            },
        ]
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
]
```